# Enter Key Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, calculator

I'm currently making a calculator app for my .NET class. The calculator works perfectly fine when I use the buttons. But when I use keys on the keyboard, it doesn't work so well. For example, when I press the Enter key, I want the calculator to calculate the problem in the text box. Instead, the enter presses the button I had last clicked which leads to issues. How can I prevent this from happening?

I know that's a odd explanation, but I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: You could ensure that your equals button always has focus.

Comment: Consider using [`KeyBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Keybinding as above or monitor KeyUp and act based on the key pressed.

Answer (score 1):

On the root level of your window/user control add an `InputBinding` for the return keystroke. This will intercept the keystroke and execute your command as if you had clicked the button (assuming it's `Command` property is also bound to that command).

Example with a UserControl:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding EvaluateCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```